# SQL: Rule Mining from an Item set

Tags: sql, combinations, permutation, rule, mining

Hey mates I am trying to implement an association rule mining in a vertica db: So far I got the heavy lifting done by finding the frequent itemsets however I still need to generate the rules. Here is an example:

Initial table:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| item1  | item2 | item3 |
+--------+-------+-------+
| A      | B     | C     |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

With 3 items I can generate 6 rules, a rule has a rule body and a rule head. This would result in the following table:

```
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| ItemB1  | ItemB2  | ItemH1 | ItemH2 |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| A       | Null    | B      | C      |
| B       | Null    | A      | C      |
| C       | Null    | A      | B      |
| A       | B       | C      | Null   |
| A       | C       | B      | Null   |
| B       | C       | A      | Null   |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

This is a very abstract example, in reality there is more than one item set and more than 3 items in one item set. I found some papers that discuss association rule mining and claim that this part is trivial. Guess not so trivial to me.

Thanks

Comment: I have two chapters on this subject in my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  Hence, I think the question is too broad for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Buy @GordonLinoff 's book!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks you very much Reading the book right now